# Contagem decrescente ultilizando a hora atual em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Galera eu achei esse contador em Javascript na internet e preciso configurar ele da seguinte forma:

Ao dar **22 horas** ele inicia a contagem, a contagem vai até às **15 horas** do dia seguinte, aí no dia seguinte ao dar **22 horas novamente**, ele iniciará de novo e assim em diante, só que eu não sei configurar ele porque eu não entendo nada de Javascript, se alguém puder dar uma força ai, agradeço desde já. Segue o código:

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
    var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
    var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
    var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function updateClock(){
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if(t.total<=0){
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
    }

    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}

var deadline = 'December 31 2015 00:00:50 UTC+0200';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <span class="days"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92691/4808